# Add page number on which a citation call-out occurs to formatted bibliographic items?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I came across a thesis which has a feature in its references. Each reference includes the page number(s) of which the reference is cited. Is this possible to do using Latex? I found it really interesting to use.

Apologies for the image being in French.

[image: citation]

Comment: the backref package and biblatex offer that.

Comment: There are numerous other similar questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-referencing?tab=Votes